# Changing ImageView position based on angle of rotation

Tags: java, 2d, animation, rotation, javafx

I am trying to make an `ImageView` change its position based on the direction it is facing.

```
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Demo extends Application {

    public void start(Stage window) {
        window.setTitle("Changing ImageView position based on angle of rotation");

        int speed = 10; // You can modify the speed here

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(new Image("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTBJoRKh1UKimWTSLdabW2b8RSLDeSgMfSqqg&usqp=CAU"));
        imageView.setX(100);
        imageView.setY(100);

        imageView.setRotate(65); // This is where you can change the angle of rotation

        Group root = new Group();
        root.getChildren().add(imageView);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        window.setScene(scene);

        final long[] lastNanoTime = {System.nanoTime()};

        new AnimationTimer() {
            @Override
            public void handle(long currentTime) {
                double elapsedTime = (currentTime - lastNanoTime[0]) / 1000000000.0;
                lastNanoTime[0] = currentTime;

                imageView.setX(imageView.getX() + Math.sin(Math.toRadians(imageView.getRotate())) * speed * elapsedTime);
                imageView.setY(imageView.getY() + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(imageView.getRotate())) * speed * elapsedTime);

            }
        }.start();

        window.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The above code is based on the code I am using. You can adjust the degrees accordingly to see the issue. The `ImageView` does not move in the direction it is facing. Note: I found a random .png file online for the purpose of this demo. You can substitute with a different image in you own code in order to better visualize the problem.

The issue is, the `ImageView` does not move in the direction it is facing. When oriented vertically (0° or 180°) the `ImageView` moves backward, but when oriented horizontally (90° or 270°) it moves straight ahead like it should. When oriented diagonally, it moves somewhere in between.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was resolved on Stack Overflow. The y axis is inverted in JavaFX, so I need to use -cos(θ) instead.

Comment: Please ask each question on just one site in the StackExchange network. Cross-posting is discouraged here.

Comment: @DMGregory Understood, I'll keep that in mind for next time. Is there any way to share a question on one site if it was posted on another? This way, it can show up in both sites' feeds without the double posting.

Comment: No, there is not. Each site has a particular audience, so generally you want to choose the site whose audience you expect would give you the best answers.